# Erros usando o Vert.X

Tags: java, socket

```
C:\Unky\Web\BloodStrikeServer-master>java -cp classpath/commons.jar;classpath/fl
ex-com.jar;classpath/flex-cor.jar;classpath/junit.jar;classpath/link.jar;classpa
th/maven-com.jar;classpath/maven-sha.jar;classpath/mysql-con.jar;classpath/vertx
-cor.jar;classpath/vertx-cod.jar;classpath/netty.jar;classpath/netty-com.jar;cla
sspath/netty-buf.jar;classpath/netty-tran.jar;classpath/netty-han.jar;classpath/
netty-hanp.jar;classpath/netty-code.jar;classpath/netty-code2.jar;classpath/nett
y-res.jar;classpath/netty-resd.jar; -jar target/lobbyplayer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-fat.j
ar
===============================================================================
BloodStrike Lobby Server
Créditos: ExtremsX
Versão: 0.1 Beta
===============================================================================
Carregando Configurações
Configurações carregadas com sucesso!
Iniciando NetworkManager
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa
der.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.(ILjava/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory;)V
        at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl.(VertxImpl.java:129)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl.(VertxImpl.java:119)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl.(VertxImpl.java:115)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxFactoryImpl.vertx(VertxFactoryImpl.java:34)
        at io.vertx.core.Vertx.vertx(Vertx.java:80)
        at com.bloodstrike.lobbyserver.Main.main(Main.java:32)
        ... 5 more

C:\Unky\Web\BloodStrikeServer-master>pause
Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar. . .
```

Já não sei mais o que fazer, já tentei de tudo, mas por ser novo na área de programação, não soube resolver. Basicamente, tento iniciar o programa e ele dá esses erros.

Comment: Conheço muito pouco sobre o Vert.X, mas esse erro parece dizer que a versão do Netty que você está usando está errada.

Comment: Pode deixar, vou tentar trocar a versão do netty

Comment: Troquei as versões de todos os jars do netty para 4.1.1Final que é a obrigatória e agora está dando um erro diferente

Comment: Inseri mais apis do vertx e mudou completamente a classe do erro.

Comment: Edite a pergunta e mostre qual é o erro. Deixe bem claro no texto quais são as versões de todos os JARs que você está usando e/ou de onde você os baixou.